# how to copy the json response into an array in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a json response coming in from a php file, the json response looks as below results:

```
[
    {
        "header": "Client ID",
        "dataindex": "clientID"
    },
    {
        "header": "Client Name",
        "dataindex": "clientName"
    },
    {
        "header": "Progress Bar",
        "dataindex": "progressBar"
    }
]
```

Now I want to copy this data into an array in the following way
    var allColumns = [];

```
//loop through the json response
var singleColumn = [];
singleColumn['header'] = Client ID from the json response whose key is header
singleColumn[dataindex'] = clientID from the json response whose key is header.
```

Please note: I need to do this is extjs3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting you correctly you are getting the JSON as a string from an ajax call to your PHP handler in a string format and you want to cast it into a Javascript array of coloumn objects.

you can do it like this:

```
var allColumns = Ext.decode(YOUR PHP JSON FORMATTED RESULT);
```

this will allow you to iterate over the result set as an in memory javascript array of objects like this:

```
for(var i=0 ; i < allColumns.length; i++){
    allColumns[i].header ...
    allColumns[i].dataindex ...
}
```

I hope I got you right...